# How to fix "Site not Configured" error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that was hosted on namecheap's Easywp. I just changed hosting to shared hosting, and had to backup then restore on the new hosting (used Wpvivid plugin).

Everything on the admin side seems perfect but when I try to see the site on the client facing side I get an error message:

> "Not Configured. Please visit Admin section first"

I have tried using the 'plugin detective' plugin, it scans all plugins but finds no culprit, and funnily, it shows my site functioning well but the moment I leave and try to test it's not.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think I found the culprit..

Comment: There was a a file in the WordPress folder (.hcflag) deleted it and everything is fine..someone should tell me whether I unknowingly did wrong..thanks